# Grep folders but not subfolders

Tags: bash, grep

I have files and folders in a directory. I want to assign to a variable only specific folders, but not their subfolders/files. 
I am trying with:

```
variable=$(find $PWD -type d | grep "_data.bedpostX")
```

However, this gives me also the subfolders inside the `_data.bedpostx` folders. How do I restrict grep to only the `_data.bedpostX` folders?

Comment: If you want all folders named `_data.bedpostX`, then the simplest `find` command is `find "$PWD" -type d -path "*/_data.bedpostX"`.

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I restrict grep to only the _data.bedpostX folders?

Add `-maxdepth 1` to the `find` command:

```
variable=$(find $PWD -maxdepth 1  -type d | grep "_data.bedpostX")
```

`-maxdepth levels`

> Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the command line arguments. `-maxdepth 0` means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.

Source [find Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it does not work, but I get the error message "find: illegal option -- m". This is my bash version: 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: @samb Try moving `$PWD` before `-maxdepth`

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` may not be necessary, did you try:

```
variable=(*/_data.bedpostX/)
```

or if `_data.bedpostX` is a suffix:

```
variable=(*/*_data.bedpostX/)
```

(The final `/` restricts the expansion to directories)